# frequent contacts/ relevant people using MS Graph-API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the frequent contacts using the graph-API tried using the [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people](http://I%20am%20trying%20to%20get%20the%20frequent%20contacts%20using%20the%20graph-API%20tried%20using%20the%20https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people)

This returns the contacts. I see a property called "relevanceScore" in the "ScoredEmailAddresses". I don't see this changing when I drop email or some one dropping email or IMing. I am also getting the marketing accounts from the Microsoft which mail about the billing. Is there a way to get only the requently contacted people using the MS Graph-API? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assume you want to get the frequent contacts.

Base on my test, we can use this Ms Graph API:`/me/people`,

it will retrieve a collection of person ordered by their relevance to the user.

Refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/scoredemailaddress), since the relevance score of the email address is determined by the user's communication and collaboration patterns and business 
relationships, we can not see any changing when dropping some email

Answer (score 1):

The RelevanceScore property should only be used to determine the relative importance of results from this API within the results from a single call to the API.

The absolute value must be considered unstable and may change. So don't write code that makes some cut off based on the range of values you see in this property. You also cannot compare values across different calls to the API, the value of relevance score may be different for the same contact for different queries.

API docs can be seen here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/people_example